# Inequality (7) in Blackwell Macqueen Polya Urn paper

Tags: probability

Let $X_i \in \mathcal{X}$ be random elements. Call $(X_n)$ a Polya sequence with parameter $\mu$ (where $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{X}$) if for every $B \subset \mathcal{X}$, the predictive distributions are given by
\begin{align*}
P(X_{n+1}\in B \mid X_1,\dots,X_n) = \frac{\mu(B) + \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}(B)}{\mu(\mathcal{X}) + n}.
\end{align*}
Denote this distribution as $m_n \doteq \frac{\mu+n\pi_n}{\mu(\mathcal{X})+n}$, where $\pi_n$ is the empirical distribution on $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. Let $I_j$ be the indicator of the event that $X_j$ is different from all $X_i$ with $i<j$ and define
\begin{align*}
f_{nj} &\doteq \begin{cases}
 I_j m_n(X_j) \hspace{1em} &1\leq j \leq n \\
0 &j > n.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
For any $B\subset\mathcal{X}$, write
\begin{align*}
s_{nr}\doteq \sum_{1\leq j \leq r : x_j \in B} f_{nj}.
\end{align*}
It is claimed in the paper that for $1 \leq r \leq n$, we have
\begin{align*}
s_{nr} \leq m_r(B).
\end{align*}

Here is what I think it a counter example.

Let $\mathcal{X} = [2] = \{1,2\}$, $r = 2$, $n=3$, and $B=\{2\}$. Suppose we observe the sequence $(X_1,X_2,X_3) = (1,2,2)$. Then
\begin{align*}
s_{nr} &= \frac{\mu(X_2)+3\pi_3(X_2)}{\mu([2])+3}=\frac{\mu(2)+2}{\mu([2])+3} \\
m_r(B) &= \frac{\mu(2)+2\pi_2(2)}{\mu([2])+2}= \frac{\mu(2)+1}{\mu([2])+2}.
\end{align*}
Supposing that $\mu(2) = 0.01$ and $\mu(1) = 0.99$, then we have $s_{nr} \approx \frac{2}{4}= \frac{1}{2}$ and $m_r(B) \approx \frac{1}{3}$, so that $m_r(B) < s_{nr}$.

Here is a link to the original paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176342372 It is the first inequality in expression (7) that I am confused about.

Comment: This is perhaps better asked on Math Overflow.